# Can I make a Tk button's background color change only while it's being held down?

Tags: python, tkinter

[Black window with a white button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha7Wk.png)

when i hold it down i want it to be another color when i hold the button without releasing it

[Black window with a light grey button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehldy.png)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg="Black")
button = Button(root, text='Ejemplo',bg='white')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Notice how I changed the question title to be more descriptive of what you're trying to accomplish, so someone could know what your question is about without needing to click through and read the body; please try to do this yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the color with `activebackground="colorname"`:

Color Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

win= tk.Tk()
win.geometry("300x250")
win.config(bg="Black")

#Define hover functions
def on_enter(e):
    button.config(background='OrangeRed3', foreground= "white")

def on_leave(e):
    button.config(background= 'SystemButtonFace', foreground= 'black')
   
#Create color Button active and non active
button = tk.Button(win, text= "Ejemplo", font= ('Helvetica 13 bold'), fg='red', bg='white', activebackground="lightgray", activeforeground="red")
button.pack(pady= 20)

#Bind the Enter and Leave Events to the Button
button.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
button.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
win.mainloop()
```